# How to get the role id from the role name?

Tags: loop, user-roles

I need to retrieve the id of a role by giving it roles name.
For example:

```
if( current_user_can('editor') ) {
 //here I want to retrieve the id of editor.
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try buildin function [get_users](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users). The code should be like that:

```
$args = array(
    'role' => 'editor'
);
$editors = get_users($args);
foreach ($editors as $user) {
    echo '<li>' . $user->ID . '</li>';
}
```